# Print a list of number using While loop and Do While loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to implement the while and do while loop without using an actual array to print an list of number. Here is my code and the output I want.
My code

```
console.log("While Loop")
let j = 0;
while(j < 5){
    j += 1;
    console.log (j);
}

console.log("Do While Loop")
var i = 0; //set varible i = 0
do {
    i += 1; //return i + 1 to i
    console.log (i);
}
while (i < 5); //where i suppose to less than 5
```

Actual Output I want:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 1
4 3 2 1
3 2 1
2 1
1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two things here:

1. You need an inner loop to create the countdown of numbers.
2. If you are only using JavaScript, you need to form a string with your output and then use `console.log()` to print. This is because `console.log()` will append a newline.

The example below will print the first half of the triangle.

```js
console.log("While Loop")
let j = 1;
while (j <= 5) {
  let k = 1;
  let str = "";
  while (k <= j) {
    str += k + " ";
    k++;
  }
  j += 1;
  console.log(str);
}
```

If you are using Node.js you can use `process.stdout.write` to print to the same line and then explicitly write the newline character when needed.

```
console.log("While Loop")
let j = 1;
while (j <= 5) {
  let k = 1;
  while (k <= j) {
    process.stdout.write(k + " ");
    k++;
  }
  j += 1;
  process.stdout.write("\n");
}
```